# How to implement face id authentication in react native android?

Tags: android, react-native, bioinformatics, touch-id, face-id

I want to implement face authentication and TouchID (finger) in react native for both platform android and ios. I've implemented IOS side face authentication and  TouchId authentication. I am using react-native-touch-id library

In android when i detect face id and try to authenticate with face but it takes finger instead of face.

How can i Implemented Both face and Touch id in android side for React-native app?

Answer (score 1):

try with this package, it supports both

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-biometrics

P.S please install correct version depending of your react-native version

Comment: I am using the same but the face is not working in android it takes the finger only not the face. do you have any idea how can i implement face auth only ?

Comment: I think this is because Face-Id and Touch-Id are iOS only. and you still seem to get Touch-Id working as Biometrics on android defaults to what you are using for your lock screen (sometimes it also depends on your device manufacturer) In the package also its already mentioned ios only

Answer (score 1):

My straight answer would be NO. The justification is that Android has never shipped FaceID/Face unlock from its own in the Stock version or core API. The Face ID/Face unlock solutions we get in android are from vendors who have indulged in android on top of the core APIs as third-party integration. I assume no one can write an interface on top of hundreds of different implementations to support such a feature from a single API.

For Face ID in iOS, you can refer to:- [https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT208108#:~:text=Face%20ID%20uses%20the%20TrueDepth,only%20to%20the%20Secure%20Enclave](https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT208108#:%7E:text=Face%20ID%20uses%20the%20TrueDepth,only%20to%20the%20Secure%20Enclave).

For Android Authentication you can refer to:- https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/biometric/auth/package-summary?hl=en

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).